In Python's `logging` package, is `basicConfig()` just a convenience wrapper around the usual configuration methods?
To me, it feels like an inconsistent API to have the root logger configured one way:
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

while all other loggers are configured another way:
mylogger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
mylogger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

What's the mental model I should have for basicConfig()? Should I view it as a special-case convenience method that internally calls all the usual individual configuration methods on the root logger object, like this?
import logging
logging.basicConfig()  # (creates an implicit handler)
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

Side note - at first I tried this:
import logging
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)  # only WARN or worse printed

and I was confused because the output was limited to WARN or worse. Then I realized that in this case, no handler existed at all, causing log events to fall back to the "handler of last resort" which has a hardcoded level of WARN.
By calling basicConfig() with no arguments, a basic default handler was created for the root logger.
Another solution was to explicitly create a handler for the root logger:
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

ch = logging.StreamHandler()
logging.getLogger().addHandler(ch)

formatter = logging.Formatter('MY HANDLER - %(asctime)s - %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)


Yes, basicConfig() is just a convenience method.
